# Write-Host adds "PS>" at the end of prompt?

Tags: powershell, prompt

If I use `write-host` to define my prompt, Powershell adds "PS>" automatically at the end. How can I use `write-host` so that it doesn't do that?

```
function prompt {
    '> '
}

#prompt:
#>

function prompt {
    write-host '> ' -foregroundcolor "green"
}

#prompt:
#>
#PS>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved; do this:

```
function prompt {
    write-host '>' -foregroundcolor "green" -nonewline
    ' '
}

#prompt:
#>
```

Comment: function prompt is expected to return a prompt string.  When you use Write-Host you are bypassing the return value and writing directly to the host.  If PowerShell observes that the prompt function doesn't return anything or an empty string, it uses a default prompt.  As you have discovered returning any non-empty string will cause PowerShell to use that string instead of the default prompt.

Comment: If you don't want any spaces at the end of the prompt, you can add " `b" (Space + Backspace).